# How can std::reference_wrapper<int> use operator+= if std::reference_wrapper doesn't have operator+=?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Thank you all, I didn't even know about user-defined conversion function and how it works.

---

Why is it possible to use `std::reference_wrapper<int>::operator+=`, if such an operator does not exist, are there some implicit conversions?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

using boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr;

template <typename C>
void test(C c)
{
    c += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    test(a);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    test(std::ref(a));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3
4
```

To check that template works perfectly fine:

```cpp
void test_2(std::reference_wrapper<int> c)
{
    c += 1;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 3;
    test_2(std::ref(a));
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
4
```

Still works as before. How is that possible?

Funny thing, that in `auto d = b + c`, `d` has an integer type.

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto b = std::ref(a);
    auto c = std::ref(a);
    auto d = b + c;
    std::cout << type_id_with_cvr<decltype(d)>).pretty_name() << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
int
```

Comment: "are there some implicit conversions?"   Implicit conversion is pretty much the whole reason that `std::reference_wrapper` exists.  As a result, you are **not** invoking `std::reference_wrapper::operator+=()`

Comment: It's a reference wrapper, it acts like a reference...

Comment: It has `operator T& ()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because it's [implicitly convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/get) to a reference to `T`:

```cpp
/* constexpr [c++20] */ operator T& () const noexcept;
```

In your case, it's implicitly convertible to an `int&`.

---

This ability to be implicitly convertible to an `int&` is also what would make it possible for you to define your function to take an `int&` while passing it a `std::reference_wrapper<int>`:

```cpp
void test_2(int& c)       // <--+
{                         //    |
    c += 1;               //    |
}                         //    |
int main() {              //    |
    // ...                //    |
    test_2(std::ref(a));  // >--+
}
```